# Trying to run Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Want to do some Python programming and downloaded "Classic" from here.

Java is installed but running the exe leads to a error saying how it can't find my java jre. It's looking in the unzipped folder. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

It probably looks in the folder because it can't find the Java install. I think I'd try reinstalling Java.

Comment: @bobber205 That's weird. Could it be that Aptana bundles a JRE? You could try 'java -version' in a command line to make sure it is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Java is in your `PATH`. What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 7. Here's my PATH.
C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server;C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\bin;C:\depot_tools;C:\Python26;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java